# What is the NestJS equivalent to expressjs server.on('listening', ...)

Tags: express, nestjs

I try to port an application to NestJS but I have not found the 'NestJS way' of listening for a successful server connection.

From the old app

```
server.on('listening', async function (): Promise<void> {
    ...
});
```

In the new app I currently have placed some code after the `listen` call...

```
await app.listen(options.port);
// do anything when the server listens
```

...but that's not the same as an event handler. I don't know if 'listen' events can come multiple times (reconnects?!) but there has to be a way to listen for that event for example decoupled in other code parts?!

In the docs I have found the `onApplicationBootstrap()` lifecycle hook method but that's called *"once all modules have been initialized, but before listening for connections."*

I thought about getting the HttpAdapter or Server ask if it is instanceof ExpressAdapter and do something like *.on('listen',...* when I find the right instance, but at least in  the @types I haven't found the right way of doing this and it smells like a hack.

Can someone please point me to the place in the docs or show me how to do this preferably in an **adapter-agnostic NestJS way?** Seems like I search for the wrong things.

Comment: What's the reason you're wanting to add an `on` event handler? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The app sends an email to operations@... to recognize (re)connects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the `getHttpAdapter` but `getHttpServer`!

The important parts are

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
const serverInstance = app.getHttpServer() as Server;
serverInstance.on('listening', ...);
```

Unfortunately `app.getHttpServer` returns an object of type any. `app.listen` returns the same instance but the type is `Server`.